# How to rotate a 3D object placed on detected 3D object according to detected object rotation?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, detect

I have scan the object using (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects)! and saved to the document directory. Later, I read, detected and placed 3D object on it but the orientation did not fit according to the detected object orientation. I could not the way how to do or how to use referenceObject extent or center properties of ARReeferenceObject.

Can you help me rotate 3D object according to the rotation of the detected object?

```
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    if let objectAnchor = anchor as? ARObjectAnchor
    {
        let referenceObject = objectAnchor.referenceObject
        let imageName = referenceObject.name ?? "no name"


        //TODO : overlay 3D Object
        let overlayNode = self.getArrowNode(withImageName: imageName)
        overlayNode.opacity = 1
        overlayNode.position = SCNVector3Make(anchor.transform.columns.3.x,anchor.transform.columns.3.y, anchor.transform.columns.3.z)


        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(overlayNode)

        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.label.text = "3D Object Detected: \"\(imageName)\""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `objectAnchor` has a `.transform` property combining position, scale and orientation. Whether rotation can readily be extracted from that, I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you adding your overlay to the `rootNode`? When you add your node directly to the `node` you get in the delegate method the position and rotation of your overlay is relative to the detected object. Also, if ARKit updates the position of your detected object, your overlay will be moved as well

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. @jlsiewert, I want to put object only once when detect the 3D object and to remain there until I remove it.